# Making lists. First list can have the same number, second will be price, trying to make a third list that if theyre the same number it adds prices

Tags: java, list, arraylist

First off, sorry for the terrible title I don't know how to describe this well. I have a sql file with a table with two columns (number and price), in java im extracting the data and have stored them into two seperate lists. Some of the numbers in the column are the same eg (100, 100, 101) and correlate to a different price eg (50, 40, 60). I need to find a way to add all the prices together that have the same column value, so an output like (90, 60). The lists are in order so index one of my list named number will go with index one of my list named price. A small example of the lists would be:

```
ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> price = new ArrayList<Integer>();

number.add("100");
number.add("100");
number.add("101");
number.add("101");
number.add("101");
number.add("102");
number.add("103");
number.add("103");

price.add(50);
price.add(150);
price.add(20);
price.add(200);
price.add(75);
price.add(40);
price.add(100);
price.add(125);
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all, got it working now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `HashMap<String, Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the size of `number` and `price` is the same. You can do something like this:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> sumForNumber = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {
    String key = number.get(i);
    sumForNumber.put(key, sumForNumber.getOrDefault(key, 0)  + price.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code helps you

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {
    String num = number.get(i);
    if (result.containsKey(num)) {
        Integer sum = result.get(num);
        result.put(num, sum + price.get(i));
    } else {
        result.put(num, price.get(i));
    }
}
```